# Is there a way to adjust the Vim screen padding margin, or Konsole's?

Tags: margin

I'd like to write and edit files and add a padding, or frame the text with margin of blank space between the text and the terminal window's edge. I don't know if that's the correct terminology, but I don't want the text flush against the edges.  Is there a way to adjust the Vim screen padding margin?

Also, the terminal program I use is called "Konsole"  Maybe there is a way to make adjustments for it, rather than Vim?

Comment: There are plugins for "distraction-free writing" that do something like this. Perhaps you could steal a page out of one of their books (or use one of the plugins). One example is https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim and one way to start digging if you want only the specific feature rather than a plugin dependency might be to trace how resizes are handled, https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim/blob/master/autoload/goyo.vim#L85

Comment: You are right, some terminal programs allow you to add a border so the text is not flushed against the edges. For instance, `gnome-terminal`, `xterm`, and `st` all allow this. I don't know if `konsole` allows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Konsole's profile at `~/.local/share/konsole/` and under the `[General]` section add the following:

```
TerminalMargin=4
```

This example is taken from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9lqtzv/does_anyone_know_how_to_add_padding_to_konsole/).

Comment: It works!  Those units appear to represent pixels. (definitely not characters)